# How to get data from Wordpress website (LAMP stack) to Android app in nearly realtime?

Tags: php, android, wordpress, apache, server-sent-events

I have a Wordpress website with a working order system. Now I want to make an Android app which displays every new order in a list view **as soon as the order was made.**

The last two days I thought about the following solutions:

1. Simple HTTP GET requests every 10 seconds
2. Websockets
3. MySQL binary log + Pusher [Link](https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-mysql-java)
4. Server Sent Events

My thoughts (working with a **LAMP** stack):

1. Simple HTTP requests are obviously the most ineffective solution.
2. I figured out that websockets and Apache aren't working well together.
3. Feels quite hacky and I want to avoid any 3rd party service if I can.

**4**. Looks like this is the optimal way for me, however there are some problems with Apache/php and Server Sent Events from what I experienced.

I tried to implement a simple demo script but I don't understand why some of them are using an infinite while loop to keep the connection open and others don't.
Here is an [example without a loop](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) and [here with an infinite loop](https://www.howopensource.com/2014/12/introduction-to-server-sent-events/), also [here](https://www.kevinchoppin.co.uk/blog/server-sent-events-in-php)
In addition to that, when I tested the variant with the infinite loop, my whole page won't load because of that sleep() function. It looks like the whole server freezes whenever I use it.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix that? Or do you have other suggestions?

That is the code that causes trouble (copied from [here](https://www.kevinchoppin.co.uk/blog/server-sent-events-in-php)) and added a missing curly bracket:

```
<?php

    // make session read-only
    session_start();
    session_write_close();

    // disable default disconnect checks
    ignore_user_abort(true);

    // set headers for stream
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // Is this a new stream or an existing one?
    $lastEventId = floatval(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"] : 0);
    if ($lastEventId == 0) {
        $lastEventId = floatval(isset($_GET["lastEventId"]) ? $_GET["lastEventId"] : 0);
    }

    echo ":" . str_repeat(" ", 2048) . "\n"; // 2 kB padding for IE
    echo "retry: 2000\n";

    // start stream
    while(true){

        if(connection_aborted()){
            exit();
        }

        else{

            // here you will want to get the latest event id you have created on the server, but for now we will increment and force an update
            $latestEventId = $lastEventId+1;

            if($lastEventId < $latestEventId){

                echo "id: " . $latestEventId . "\n";
                echo "data: Howdy (".$latestEventId.") \n\n";
                $lastEventId = $latestEventId;
                ob_flush();
                flush();

            }

            else{

                // no new data to send
                echo ": heartbeat\n\n";
                ob_flush();
                flush();

            }

        }

        // 2 second sleep then carry on
        sleep(2);

    }
?>
```

I'm thankful for every advice I can get! :)

**EDIT:**
The main idea is to frequently check my MySQL database for new entries and if there is a new order present, format the data nicely and send the information over SSE to my android application.
I already found libraries to receive SSEs on android, the main problem is on the server side.

Comment: keyword: Long Polling

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but implementing long polling with php and Apache apparently involves using the sleep() function, too. So I guess I will run into the same problem with freezing the site. Or am I missing something here?
Possible example of long polling with php:
[link](https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling/blob/master/server/server.php)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I think you could implement SSE - Server sent events, which is part of HTML5 standard. It is a one-way communication from server to client. It needs html/javascript and a backend language, e.g PHP.

The client will subscribe on events and when subscription is up and running the server will send any updates from the input data. As standard the update will be visible each 3 seconds. This can be adjusted though.

I would recommend you to first create a basic functioning web-browser-client as a start. When and if it is working as you expect, only then you would judge about the effort of building the client as an app.

You would probably need to add functions on the client-side, such as start/stop the subscription.

My understanding of users not recommending the combination of (server sent events) and Apache is the lack of control how many open connections there are and what would control the continuously need of closing of connections. This could lead to sever server performance problems.

Seems using for example node.js would not cause that problem.

**Here are some start link:**

MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Stream Updates with Server-Sent Events:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what Server Sent Events are and that they are probably the best solution to my problem. That's why I tried to implement them, as already stated in my question. However, because of the way Apache handles these, I might have to find a different solution. Using Node.js is sadly not an option, I have to stick to the LAMP stack.
There has to be a solution for this. I can't imagine I'm the only one having that kind of problem.

Comment: @Apocabal: I am preparing a Server sent event solution, with Apache and PHP. My understanding is that you can create a control mechanism that would reside in PHP (assuming you do not incorporate a database). I have the solution up and running with data stored in json format as external file. Currently I take the stream from 3 files and I am investigating if possible to create only one open connection and let the 3 stream share that connection. I will also add on frontend the possibility to open/close the stream.

Comment: @Apocabal: Could you be more specific in what your question is?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I need to get the information about new orders from my MySQL database, so unfortunately there is a database involed. I edited my question accordingly.